# What SQlite datatype maps to clr datatype double?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I cant find any SQLite datatype that is mapped to double by the entity framework.

I have tried REAL, DOUBLE, FLOAT, nothing seems to work, i always end up with a float as the converted datatype of the c# properties.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using [system.data.sqlite](/questions/tagged/system.data.sqlite), you may find some tips from `TypeAffinity` from [documentation](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/Doc/SQLite.NET.chm).

Short history:

SQLite only supports one kind of floating point, corresponding to `System.Double`.

So, whatever floating type you supply, [system.data.sqlite](/questions/tagged/system.data.sqlite) will convert it to `System.Double`.

Comment: Using EF my results are quite the opposite, I only get System.Single: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002246/why-both-real-and-float-get-mapped-to-single-instead-of-double

Answer (score 0):

When I first started using EF, I got my mappings references from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661811/using-ef-code-first-to-generate-tables-with-columns-that-have-special-sql-data-t). According to it, `double` is converted to `float` when the DB is created. Of course, we're talking about MSSQL here.

Anyway, since you said that you always end up with `float`, I believe this is the standard procedure from EF.
You can Google for SQLite mappings, but every result I get was kinda outdated. 
Some examples: [this one (3rd party, but nevertheless)](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteType.html)
[This one](http://www.alinq.org/ALinq_Document/1.Getting_Started/5.CLR_Type_AND_SQL_Type_Default_Mapping.aspx)
and the official [SQLite Docs](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

My guess is: `Double` is mapped as `float` with EF.
It would be great if someone could correct me!

Best regards.