# Why both "real" and "float" get mapped to "Single" instead of "Double"?

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite

I am using System.Data.SQLite 1.0.90 with VS2013 and EntityFramework 5 in Model-First mode (=EDMX).

I created a new SQLite database containing a table:

```
CREATE TABLE [..]
  [Test1integer] integer,
  [Test2int] int,
  [Test3smallint] smallint,
  [Test4tinyint] tinyint,
  [Test5bigint] bigint,
  [Test6money] money,
  [Test7float] float,
  [Test8real] real,
  [Test9decimal] decimal,
  [Test10numeric18_5] numeric(18,5), [..]
```

The relevant parts are `Test7float` and `Test8real`.

After having executed **Update Model from Database...** the EDMX now contains this:

#### SSDL:

```
      <Property Name="Test1integer" Type="integer" />
      <Property Name="Test2int" Type="int" />
      <Property Name="Test3smallint" Type="smallint" />
      <Property Name="Test4tinyint" Type="tinyint" />
      <Property Name="Test5bigint" Type="integer" />
      <Property Name="Test6money" Type="decimal" Precision="53" Scale="0" />
      <Property Name="Test7float" Type="real" />
      <Property Name="Test8real" Type="real" />
      <Property Name="Test9decimal" Type="decimal" Precision="53" Scale="0" />
      <Property Name="Test10numeric18_5" Type="decimal" Precision="18" Scale="5" />
```

The relevant parts are `Test7float` and `Test8real`.

#### CSDL:

```
      <Property Name="Test1integer" Type="Int64" />
      <Property Name="Test2int" Type="Int32" />
      <Property Name="Test3smallint" Type="Int16" />
      <Property Name="Test4tinyint" Type="Byte" />
      <Property Name="Test5bigint" Type="Int64" />
      <Property Name="Test6money" Type="Decimal" Precision="53" Scale="0" />
      <Property Name="Test7float" Type="Single" />
      <Property Name="Test8real" Type="Single" />
      <Property Name="Test9decimal" Type="Decimal" Precision="53" Scale="0" />
      <Property Name="Test10numeric18_5" Type="Decimal" Precision="18" Scale="5" />
```

The relevant parts are `Test7float` and `Test8real`.

## Problem

`Test7float` wrongly became "real" + "Single" -- and the designer also does not allow "Double" here.

The SQLite3 docs ( http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html ) clearly state that "real" is a 8-byte IEEE floating point number and "float" is only a synonym for "real" -- so in every case "Double" (8 byte) should be preferred over "Single" (4 byte).

Am I doing something wrong or did I misunderstand something? If not: Where are things going wrong and how can I fix them?

Should I create a bug report for this?

Comment: Looks like you found a bug :) You should see if the issue was reported by someone before you, and file a new bug report as appropriate.

Comment: @Luaan do you think its a common bug in EntityFramework or just for System.Data.SQLite?

Comment: I don't see why this should be related to EntityFramework itself. EF does have support for both singles and doubles, so it is probably some faulty mapping in the SQLite "driver". I'd also try to go through configuration first, maybe there's some compatibility setting or something.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in the mapping driver.

The type used to declare a column is only used for affinity (you can declare a column as float and store blobs in it if you want).

When reporting a table structure, SQLite merely returns the SQL definition that was used to create its fields (and alter them, if applicable).

Thus your driver only has access to "float" for the field type, and likely maps it to "single" through some generic code, that may not have been written with SQLite in mind (or overridden for SQLite anyway).

Comment: Since EMDX driven model-first development has been declared deprecated I switched to code-first over a year ago and so this problem (and many more) doesn' affect me any more.

Answer (score 0):

Real sqllite data type is actually a float (http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) and the correspondant .Net framework type is Single (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx)

Comment: sqlite-real/float = 8 bytes = 64 bit = c#-Double -- I really don't get the point why you think it could be a 4 bytes (32 bit) Single