# Entity Framework: Mapping a db real to decimal? Cannot convert System.Single to System.Double

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a table with the following fields:

**dbo.AccountProbability**

```
StageKey (binary(16), not null)
AccountId (int, not null)
Probability (real, null)
IsCurrent (bit, not null)
```

It is mapped in Entity Framework like so:

```
[Table("dbo.AccountProbability")]
public partial class AccountProbability
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(16)]
    public byte[] StageKey { get; set; }

    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    public double? Probability { get; set; }

    public bool IsCurrent { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to map it to an object, in the below method, I get an error:

```
public async Task GetAccountProbabilities()
{
    var repo = GetDatabaseRepo();
    var validAcctProbs = repo.Where<AccountProbability>(
                    m => m.IsCurrent).ToList();
}


private static IDatabaseRepository GetDatabaseRepo()
{
    var context =
        new DbContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    return new DatabaseRepository(context);
}
```

It fails on `validAcctProbs` when it's putting it to list, with the error: `The 'Probability' property on 'AccountProbability' could not be set to a 'System.Single' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Double'.`

I believe that reals in TSQL are doubles in EF.

EDIT: I do not believe this is a dupe because the previous question was specifically about SQLite and faulty mappings in that driver. This is for Microsoft TSQL.

Comment: single is not integer (single precision floating point, identical to `float`). but it is correct that tsql `real` maps to .NET `double`: [mappings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896344(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why both "real" and "float" get mapped to "Single" instead of "Double"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002246/why-both-real-and-float-get-mapped-to-single-instead-of-double)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I believe that reals in TSQL are doubles in EF

Documentation is a bit ambiguous about this. We need to look it up in the implementation. The [source code of EF6](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/527ae18fe23f7649712e9461de0c90ed67c3dca9/src/EntityFramework.SqlServer/Resources/System/Data/SqlClient/System.Data.Resources.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.ProviderManifest.xml) is public, so we find:

```
<Type Name="tinyint" PrimitiveTypeKind="Byte"></Type> 
<Type Name="smallint" PrimitiveTypeKind="Int16"></Type> 
<Type Name="int" PrimitiveTypeKind="Int32"></Type> 
<Type Name="bigint" PrimitiveTypeKind="Int64"></Type> 
<Type Name="float" PrimitiveTypeKind="Double"></Type> 
<Type Name="real" PrimitiveTypeKind="Single"></Type> 
<Type Name="decimal" PrimitiveTypeKind="Decimal">
```

Let me show why this makes sense:

1. In T-SQL, starting from SQL Server 2008, [real](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql) is float(24) is a 4 byte (32 bit) floating point number.
2. In .NET, [Single](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single(v=vs.110).aspx) is `float` is a 4 byte (32 bit) floating point number.
3. In .NET, [Double](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/double) is an 8 byte (64 bit) floating point number.

Range of `real`: -3.40e38 to 3.40e38
Range of `Single`: -3.402823e38 to +3.402823e38

So there is no point using the `double?` type for your `Probability` field, because the `real` will never exhaust the precision of a `Single`.